# Let and construct versus let in sequence

Tags: coding-style, f#, ocaml

Consider this OCaml code:

```
let coupe_inter i j cases =
  let lcases = Array.length cases in
  let low,_,_ = cases.(i)
  and _,high,_ = cases.(j) in
  low,high,
  Array.sub cases i (j-i+1),
  case_append (Array.sub cases 0 i) (Array.sub cases (j+1) (lcases-(j+1)))
```

Why the expression `let ... and ... in` is used in place of a `let ... in let ... in` sequence (like F# force you to do)? This construct seems quite frequent in OCaml code.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`let x = a and y = b in c` has the effect of defining `x` and `y` "simultaneously". This means that the order of evaluation (`a` after or before `b`) is unspecified (you must *not* assume that `a` will be evaluated before), and that `x` is not bound in `b` and `y` not bound in `a`, they are only available in `c`.

I rarely use this construction, because I have been bitten in the past by the evaluation order thing. I often use the recursive variant of it, `let rec ... and ... in ...` (where all variable bound are available everywhere), however, to define mutually recursive functions.

```
let rec even n = (n = 0) || odd (n - 1)
and odd n = (n <> 0) && even (n - 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

In F# `let ... and ...` is prohibited, but you still can write:

```
let rec low,_,_ = cases.[i]
and _,high,_ = cases.[j]
```

As @gasche said, `let rec ... and ...` is mainly used for defining mutually recursive functions/types. I think using a sequence of `let` is more intuitive and less error-prone hence should be preferred.